# C# code to Export SQL Table Data to Excel on daily basis

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, export-to-excel

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC 3. I want to export data from a SQL Server table to an Excel sheet and save it in a share path on a daily basis.

How can I do this using C# code?

Comment: This is a requirements dump, not a question. Please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can't be done in Asp.net. IIS kills any processes that aren't serving a request. Thus you can't run a scheduler.

Comment: Have you considered using excel datasources?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void WriteToCsvFile(this DataTable dataTable, string filePath) 
    {
        var fileContent = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var col in dataTable.Columns) {
            fileContent.Append(col + ",");
        }

        fileContent.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);

        foreach (DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows) {

            foreach (var column in dr.ItemArray) {
                fileContent.Append("\"" + column + "\",");
            }

            fileContent.Replace(",", System.Environment.NewLine, fileContent.Length - 1, 1);
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filePath, fileContent.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is couple ways to setup this:

1. you could utilize the WebAPI to implement and action that would
   perform the export, then write a console app and schedule it to run
   on the windows Task Scheduler( basically the console app will call
   the WebAPI ie. `http://yoursite/api/doExport`).
2. You could use [Quartz.Net](http://blog.devscrum.net/2011/10/scheduling-tasks-within-an-asp-net-mvc-site-with-quartz-net/)
3. Lastly you could utilize the cachedItemCallback like [this example](http://www.radicalgeek.co.uk/Post/10/running-a-task-on-a-schedule-from-an-mvc-web-application), but since you need to run it once a day this way may not work for you.